# How to simulate iOS push notification to 1000s of devices using Javapns library - Push Notification Broadcast

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am developing a iOS application which will used by 3000 users to start with and it will grow in number upto 10,000. I have implemented push notification for the app and I am able to test it with 10-15 Devices and it is working fine.

I m using Javapns java library on the server side to process the request to my users. According to the documenatation we need to set the thread count to an optimized value so that notifications will be sent to APNS server. Currently I have set it to 10 but I dont know how to find the ideal value for thread count for 3000 users. The documentation for Javapns didnot specify clearly how to find the ideal value for a number of users or request.

How to simulate sending push notification to 3000 users, is there any tools available to do this?